# get new content of a span balise

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the content of a span balise after its content changed from "" to a not empty string. When i use alert with "$(this).html()" the content of #ac1 is appearing well but i can't insert it into #ville.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="ville" onkeyup="autocompletion('ville')"/><span id="ac1"></span>

$("#ac1").on("click",function()
    {
        $("#ville").html($(this).html());
    });
```

Do you know what's wrong? Thank you !

Comment: access `input` with `val()` instead of `html()` like this: `$("#ville").val(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## JQuery :

```js
$("#ac1").on("click", function() {
  $("#ville").val($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="ville" />
<br>
<span id="ac1">test</span>
```

---

## Vanilla JS only :

```js
function f(elem) {
  document.getElementById("ville").value = elem.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="ville" />
<br>
<span id="ac1" onclick="f(this)">test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` elements don't have `HTML` inside them. Instead of the `html()` method, you'll have to use `val()`, so your code would be:

```
$('#ville').val($(this).text());
```